# Org table spreadsheet use column name on left hand side

Tags: org-mode, org-table, formula, spreadsheet

I have the following table and formulas:

```
|   | Runde | 0 | 1 | 2 | Resultat |          % |
|---+-------+---+---+---+----------+------------|
| ! | name  |   |   |   |   result | percentage |
| # | Alice | 1 | 1 | 0 |        2 |      66.67 |
| # | Bob   | 0 | 0 | 1 |        1 |      33.33 |
#+TBLFM: $6='(+ $<<<..$>>>);N
#+TBLFM: $7='(format "%2.2f" (* (/ 100 (float (+ @3$result @4$result))) $result));N
```

Using numbers on the left hand side works fine, but it would be even better if I could do the formulas as follows:

```
#+TBLFM: $result='(+ $<<<..$>>>);N
#+TBLFM: $percentage='(format "%2.2f" (* (/ 100 (float (+ @3$result @4$result))) $result));N
```

However, as soon as I put in column names on the left, the formulas are not working properly any more. Is this a bug, or is my understanding of how the formulas work wrong?

Version:

- GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2017-09-20 on lcy01-07, modified by Debian
- org mode version from package list: `org  9.1.13  available  gnu        Outline-based notes management and organizer`

Comment: Apparently *field names* work for assignment (those defined with `^` or `_`), but *column names* don't.

Comment: Confirmed: checking the source for `org-table-get-stored-formulas`, there is a comment about named columns on LHS not being possible.

Comment: @Juancho I don't think it's theoretically impossible, as I don't see how it would create ambiguity, but maybe in terms of what org tables can currently do it is impossible. Could you make your comment an answer? Then I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simulate LHS Column Name Assignments

Simulate Left Hand Side (LHS) column name assignments using [named fields](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-features.html#Advanced-features) and a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html).

1. Update your example table and formulas as follows:

   ```
   |   | Runde |  0 |  1 |  2 | Resultat | %          |
   |---+-------+----+----+----+----------+------------|
   | ! |       | c0 | c1 | cn |          |            |
   | _ | name  |    |    |    | result   | percentage |
   | # | Alice |  1 |  1 |  0 |          |            |
   | # | Bob   |  0 |  0 |  1 |          |            |
   | # | Eve   |  1 |  1 |  1 |          |            |
   #+TBLFM: $result='(reduce '+ (vector $c0..$cn));N::$percentage='(calc-eval (format "(%i/%i)*100" $result (length (vector $c0..$cn))));%2.2f
   ```

   - **Update Details**

     - Added named column syntax for `c0`, `c1`, and `cn` which is referenced in formulas as `$c0..$cn` to allow additional columns to be added between `c0` and `cn` in future as needed.
     - Redefined `name`, `result` and `percentage` using field name syntax.
     - Added data row to table.
     - Updated `#+TBLFM:` with similar formulas whose results are assigned on the LHS to the field names `$result` and `$percentage`.
2. Define `simulate-lhs-column-name-assignments` keyboard macro using elisp `src` block.

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results silent
     (fset 'simulate-lhs-column-name-assignments
        [?\C-u ?\C-u ?\C-c ?\C-c M-down])
   #+END_SRC
   ```
3. Bind `simulate-lhs-column-name-assignments` to key or your choice, e.g. `f6` key.

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp  :results silent
     (local-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'simulate-lhs-column-name-assignments)
   #+END_SRC
   ```
4. Place point, aka cursor, inside a cell on the row which assigns field names.

   ```
   | _ | name  |    |    |    | result   | percentage |
   ```
5. Call the `simulate-lhs-column-name-assignments` keyboard macro using the assigned key, e.g. `f6` key, until the line with the field assignments is at bottom of table.

   After completing this step, your table should resemble the example below:

   ```
   |   | Runde |  0 |  1 |  2 | Resultat |          % |
   |---+-------+----+----+----+----------+------------|
   | ! |       | c0 | c1 | cn |          |            |
   | # | Alice |  1 |  1 |  0 |        2 |      66.67 |
   | # | Bob   |  0 |  0 |  1 |        1 |      33.33 |
   | # | Eve   |  1 |  1 |  1 |        3 |     100.00 |
   | _ | name  |    |    |    |   result | percentage |
   #+TBLFM: $result='(reduce '+ (vector $c0..$cn));N::$percentage='(calc-eval (format "(%i/%i)*100" $result (length (vector $c0..$cn))));%2.2f
   ```

### **Thanks for asking a great question!**

> **The code in this answer was validated using**
>   **emacs version:** GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   **org version:** 9.1.2

Comment: It is a decent workaround. Since there is no other answer showing how to use column names on the LHS, I will accept this as answer now : )